# Spring JPA returns data for wrong column

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Something as simple as a MySQL native query like this:

```
SELECT image_filename FROM article
```

using this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "summary")
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "image_filename")
    private String imageFilename;
}
```

returns the data from a different field called `summary`.  I've checked the SQL table and it does not have this issue.

The issue occurs in all sorts of other queries.  What would cause this?

Comment: Could you please post the `CREATE` statement of your table and the query you use (Is it a native query? JPA? JPQL?)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by making sure the columns in my create table statement, entity, result set mapping, and native query were all in alphabetical order (except for the primary key, which is first).

It seems very strange to me that JPA would require this, and will jumble up the columns if you don't do this.